# Webpack Uglify: Keep Certain console.logs

Tags: webpack

So I am currently using UglifyJsPlugin's drop_console option set to true, which means all console.* calls will be removed during compression.

I am now in the need of preserving certain console.log calls and haven't really found anything I can use to accomplish this.

Is there any way, any command or any option I can use to just keep some of these?

An idea could be to just keep the console.info calls for example and dropping the rest of the console.* calls but again I'm not sure that's possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

You could access the `console` object via the global object for those logs which you want to preserve.

In Node you can do:

```
global.console.log("UglifyJs won't remove me")
```

And in the browser:

```
window.console.log("UglifyJs won't remove me")
```